# What API should I use to write a sublime-text plugin to show the hints

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Like this. What API should I use to show this box?

[image: completion menu]

---

update:
I successed in sublime-text 3,but failed in sublime-text 2.Do you know why?
The code is:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CCAutoComplete(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
     def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        flag = sublime.INHIBIT_WORD_COMPLETIONS | sublime.INHIBIT_EXPLICIT_COMPLETIONS
        result = ([["abv","abv"],["abcd123","abcd"]],flag)
        return result
```

Comment: You must use a tuple for ST2 `result = ([("abv","abv"),("abcd123","abcd")], flag)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-completion panel can be manually populated with the [**on_query_completions**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/api.html?highlight=on_query_completions#sublime_plugin.EventListener.on_query_completions) listener.

To view a functioning example of it's implementation:

- Install [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer)
- Run `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` from the command palette
- Select the `CSS` package and open `css_completions.py`

Comment: I successed in showing the auto-completion  panel in sublime-text 3,but failed in sublime-text2,do you know why?The code:import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CCAutoComplete(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
   flag = sublime.INHIBIT_WORD_COMPLETIONS | sublime.INHIBIT_EXPLICIT_COMPLETIONS
   result = ([["abv","abv"],["abcd123","abcd"]],flag)
   return result

Comment: @chenhehe : I'm not too sure about ST2, since I only work with ST3. ST2 only has about 20% of the user base and is [**no longer in development**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-2-not-developed-anymore/18680/4).